# How do you apply medicine to an infant's tongue?

Tags: toddler, medicine

My baby is 1.5 years old.  She has an ulcer on her tongue and gum. The doctor gave me medicine (similar to mouth wash). I am supposed to apply this medicine to her tongue and gum, without her swallowing it.

When I returned home, I figured out it was pretty hard to keep her mouth open, and it is almost impossible to apply the medication without being bitten hard by newly-sharp teeth.

How can I get the medicine where it needs to go, without her swallowing it?

Answer (score 5):

Physically, this should be relatively straightforward, at that age they can't bite that hard - and you can use a thumb to help hold the jaw open.

But a more useful way to do this is to get her cooperation - at that age, especially if the ulcer is hurting her, help her understand what the medicine will do to help. Of course this is easier if it tastes nice, but you should be able to help her understand.

She may even be able to help apply the medicine.

Answer (score 1):

If the medicine is a gel, I would try to apply it to my finger first, then holding the mouth with the other hand, gently apply it to the sores. I have a 1.5 yr old as well, and I KNOW they wont sit still. Nor listen to "reason". So maybe try when in the highchair, as being restricted somewhat may help. You could also try putting the medicine on the back of her baby spoon, and rubbing it on that way. Also, using a Q-tip to apply it may be another viable option. I have had the same hard time trying to apply the teething gel without getting bitten. I have learned just to hold his head forward, and apply quickly. If it's an oral medication, the makers would have to expect some amount of swallowing. Follow the application with a tasty treat and a lot of praise. Hopefully she will associate medicine with feeling better and love from mommy.